# Issue with distinct mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a query

```
$getitreult = ("select distinct Project_Name,meetings.Start_date as Mdate,
    meeting_next.meetingDate as M1date, time
    from meetings left join meeting_next
        on meetings.m_id=meeting_next.fk_m_id
    where meetings.Start_date BETWEEN '27-Feb-2018' and '28-Feb-2018' or
          meetingDate BETWEEN '27-Feb-2018' and '28-Feb-2018' or
          meetings.Start_date='27-Feb-2018' or
          meetings.Start_date='28-Feb-2018' or
          meetingDate='27-Feb-2018' or
          meetingDate='28-Feb-2018'");
```

Which return

```
   Project_Name | Mdate        | M1date       | time
   BAIF - Global| 21-Feb-2018  |  27-Feb-2018   11.30
   Manage       |  20-Feb-2018 |  27-Feb-2018  | 10.30
    Test        |  20-Feb-2018 |  28-feb-2018 | 10.00
   BAIF - Global| 27-Feb-2018  |  20-Feb-2018   11.30
   Manage       |  27-Feb-2018 |  06-march-2018  | 10.30
```

I need distinct 3 project but it return twice becuase of this date.How can i solve this?please help me?expected output

```
   Project_Name | Mdate        | M1date       | time
   BAIF - Global| 21-Feb-2018  |  27-Feb-2018   11.30
   Manage       |  20-Feb-2018 |  27-Feb-2018  | 10.30
    Test        |  20-Feb-2018 |  28-feb-2018 | 10.00
```

Comment: do you want to ignore `Mdate` and `M1date` even if they are different but `Project_Name` is same?

Comment: There are two different Mdate values for project_name BAIF-GlOBAL. So you cannot get distinct values. Unless until only if you need Project_Name Column.

Comment: @NimishGupta -yes..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using a subquery to find the record for each project having the earliest `Mdate`.  The query below is essentially the same query you posted in your question, except now it includes an extra join to a subquery to restrict to the earliest start date per project.

```
SELECT
    Project_Name,
    Start_date AS Mdate,
    meetingDate AS M1date,
    time
FROM meetings m1
LEFT JOIN meeting_next m2
    ON m1.m_id = m2.fk_m_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT Project_Name, MIN(Start_date) AS min_start_date
    FROM meetings
    GROUP BY Project_Name
) t
    ON m1.Project_Name = t.Project_Name AND
       m1.Start_date   = t.min_start_date
WHERE
    m1.Start_date BETWEEN '27-Feb-2018' AND '28-Feb-2018' OR
    m2.meetingDate BETWEEN '27-Feb-2018' AND '28-Feb-2018' OR
    m1.Start_date IN ('27-Feb-2018', '28-Feb-2018') OR
    m2.meetingDate IN ('27-Feb-2018', '28-Feb-2018');
```

Note that I question your date literals, e.g. `27-Feb-2018`.  If it actually works, it means that you are storing your dates as text, which is not desirable.  If it *doesn't* work, then use ISO compliant date literals such as `2018-02-27` in place of `27-Feb-2018`.

Also, rather than aggregating by project name, it would be better to use some sort of unique ID describing each project.  This would eliminate the problem of two projects happening to have the same name.

Comment: Thanks dear..perfect

Answer (score 0):

See if this works

```
("select Project_Name,meetings.Start_date as Mdate,
    meeting_next.meetingDate as M1date, time
    from meetings left join meeting_next
        on meetings.m_id=meeting_next.fk_m_id
    group by Project_Name
    having meetings.Start_date BETWEEN '27-Feb-2018' and '28-Feb-2018' or
          meetingDate BETWEEN '27-Feb-2018' and '28-Feb-2018' or
          meetings.Start_date='27-Feb-2018' or
          meetings.Start_date='28-Feb-2018' or
          meetingDate='27-Feb-2018' or
          meetingDate='28-Feb-2018'");
```